# Is my roll completely ruined

Tags: film, 35mm, minolta

I have a Minolta supreme freedom zoom elite. Was looking at my camera and noticed the counter was at 1 when I know I’ve taken at least 3 or 4 pictures and remember it being at that number. So my guess is someone opened the back of the camera while I wasn’t home. It’s Fuji film with 36 frames and if it was opened is the whole roll garbage or can I still use it. Also have no idea how long the camera was open for.

Comment: How long the camera was open for doesn't really matter - any amount of time is bad. But, rather than just assuming it was opened, can't you ask whoever you live with?

Comment: Many years ago I had a Minolta x300 SLR on which the counter stopped working, although you could tell by the rewinder that the film was still advancing. Turned out to be a tiny nub of plastic on the disc had worn down.

Answer (score 1):

- Most likely: If the film has not caught on the take-up sprocket, the numbers will not advance. That would mean you clicked the button three times and took *no* picture (they weer all on the leader). To check, try taking another photo and see if the numbers still do not advance. In this case, just open the camera and re-thread the film on the take-up roller.
- If the back *were* opened, it depends for how long and in what illumination.

  - It could be that a few frames at the beginning are ruined.
  - It could be that there's some washed-out areas along the edges of a few more frames.
  - It could be the whole roll is ruined.

In that case, "Yah pays yer money and takes yer chances." If it's B&W and I'm doing the processing, I'd likely use up the roll quickly, develop it, and put in a fresh roll. If it's color, and I'd have to pay for processing, I might dump the roll.